# What does 'Int'l Ed' stand for?

Tags: soft-question

We say that you would like to buy either

*Principles of Mathematical Analysis (Int'l Ed)*
[image]

or
*Principles of Mathematical Analysis.*
[image]

Principles of Mathematical Analysis (Int'l Ed) costs *nearly* half as much as Principles of Mathematical Analysis.

I know that Int'l Ed stands for *international edition*. But what does (Int'l Ed) stand for, more than just *international edition*, e.g. what does the Int'l label mean to to the text and content in the book? It just drives me nuts! I have a really hard time finding an answer by simply searching the web, so I ask the question here.

**What are the differences between two books, or any two books - one book labeled Int'l Ed and the other book not?**

Comment: I wouldn't imagine that there was a formal definition.  A publisher might release one version for a domestic market and another version internationally.  These may be more or less identical or there may be large scale differences.  If you have access to both books I'd compare Table of Contents, total pages, things like that.

Comment: [*This page*](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/14318/difference-between-international-edition-of-a-book-and-a-non-international-one) seems to have an answer. I used an international edition of the baby Rudin which is soft-covered (yes, it is the same one in your first image), and until now I did not know that US edition is hard-covered!

Comment: An international edition is cheaper. In your case, the price relation is almost two to one.

Answer (score -3):

My first thought was "international education" but then seeing the context, it is clearly "international edition".

Comment: Quote from the OP's question: "I know that Int'l Ed stands for international edition. But what does (Int'l Ed) stand for, more than just international edition, e.g. what does the Int'l label mean to to the text and content in the book? It just drives me nuts! I have a really hard time finding an answer by simply searching the web, so I ask the question here."